# unable to acess the admin console of Wildfly when using wildfly-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, interface, admin, wildfly

I am new to Wildfly (8.0.0.Final) and maven. I used the standalone script to start WildFly server and I've added a management user called admin to be able to acess the admin interface. But when I start the wildfly server using wildfly maven plugin like this :

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
            /configuration> 
    </plugin>
```

and trying to access the admin console I see a prompt message ""Your WildFly Application Server is running. However you have not yet added any users to be able to access the admin console.""

Any clue??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all why don't you use the latest versions of a) wildlfy server: `8.2.0` and b) wildlfy maven plugin: `1.0.2.Final`

Now if you want to use maven to both start the server and deploy your app then you need to tell to maven where your server is located by using `-Djboss-as.home` property (info taken from http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-maven-plugin-tech-tip-9/) or set the [`<jbossHome/>`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html#jbossHome) configuration tag.

If the property `-Djboss-as.home` or `<jbossHome/>` is not specified WildFly is downloaded and started and the application is deployed to it. You will find at the target directory of your project the newly downloaded server, in my case: `mavenWildfyTest\target\wildfly-run\wildfly-8.2.0.Final`
Check into the bin folder and you will find `add-user.bat`. If you run it you will add a user and you will be able to log in to the  management console of the downloaded wildlfy server.

However, I believe, this is not what you want but instead you want to use maven plugin to deploy apps in your own Wildfly server.

In that case you have two options:

- start the server beforehand by using the standalone script (bat or sh) and then use `mvn wildfly:deploy` or
- use `mvn wildfly:run` with `-Djboss-as.home` defined, in my case: `mvn wildfly:run
  -Djboss-as.home=K:\app_servers\wildfly-8.1.0.Final`